# Concurrent dictionary best way to remove Collection type values

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, collections, concurrentdictionary

I have many clients where each client is having multiple simultaneous tunnels (data fetching middleware).

I have to manage all the clients with live tunnels of each of the client.

My `Tunnel` class is having many properties and functions, I am showing only useful properties As :

```
 public class Tunnel : IEquatable<Tunnel>
 {
       public Guid UID { get; private set; }

        public Tunnel(){
            this.UID = Guid.NewGuid(); ;
        }
        public Tunnel(Guid uid_)
        {
            this.UID = uid_;
        }
       public bool Equals(Tunnel other)
     {
         return other != null && other.UID == this.UID;
     }

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         var other = obj as Tunnel;
         return other != null && other.UID == this.UID;
     }
     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return this.UID.GetHashCode();
     }

        public static bool operator ==(Tunnel tunnel1, Tunnel tunnel2)
        {
            if (((object)tunnel1) == null || ((object)tunnel2) == null)
            { return Object.Equals(tunnel1, tunnel2); }

            return tunnel1.Equals(tunnel2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Tunnel tunnel1, Tunnel tunnel2)
        {
            if (((object)tunnel1) == null || ((object)tunnel2) == null)
            { return !Object.Equals(tunnel1, tunnel2); }

            return !(tunnel1.Equals(tunnel2));
        }

      // 10+ other properties
 }
```

I have `ClientConnections` class which manages all the clients with their LiveTunnels as :

```
public class ClientsConnections 
{
    internal readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Object, Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel>> ClientsSessions;
    
    public ClientsConnections(){
        this.ClientsSessions = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel>>();
    }
    
    public Tunnel AddOrUpdateClientTunnel(Object ClientID, Tunnel tnl)
    {
        if (tnl.ClientID == null) { tnl.ClientID = ClientID; }
        this.ClientsSessions.AddOrUpdate(ClientID, new Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel>() { { tnl.UID, tnl } }, (oldkey, liveTunnels) =>
        {
            lock (liveTunnels)
            {
                if (liveTunnels.ContainsKey(tnl.UID))
                {
                    liveTunnels[tnl.UID] = tnl;
                }
                else
                {
                    liveTunnels.Add(tnl.UID, tnl);
                }
            }
            return liveTunnels;
        });
        return tnl;
    }
   
    public bool RemoveClientTunnel(Object ClientID, Tunnel tnl)
    {
        Boolean anyRemoved = false;
        
        // When there is no tunnel i.e. current tunnel is the last in ClientSessions, remove entire key value from Concurrent Dictionary
        if(this.ClientsSessions.ContainsKey(ClientID))
        {
           Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel> removedTunls;
           
            Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel> liveTunls = this.ClientsSessions[ClientID];
            lock (liveTunls) 
            {
                if (liveTunls.ContainsKey(tnl.UID))
                {
                    liveTunls.Remove(tnl.UID);
                   if(!anyRemoved){ anyRemoved = true;}
                }
            }
            if (liveTunls.Count == 0)
            {
                //No tunnels for this ClientID, remove this client from Concurrent Dictionary
                this.ClientsSessions.TryRemove(ClientID, out removedTunls);

                if (removedTunls.Count != 0)
                {
                    // Oops There were some Livetunnels, add them back
                    AddOrUpdateClientTunnelRestore(removedTunls);
                }
            }
        }

        return anyRemoved;
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateClientTunnelRestore( Dictionary<Guid, Tunnel> tnltoAdd)
    {
        bool anyAdded = false;
        Object ClientId = tnltoAdd[tnltoAdd.Keys.First()].ClientID;
        this.ClientsSessions.AddOrUpdate(ClientId, tnltoAdd, (oldkey, liveTunnels) =>
        {
            lock (liveTunnels)
            {
                foreach (Tunnel tmpTnl in liveTunnels.Values)
                {
                    if (!liveTunnels.ContainsKey(tmpTnl.UID))
                    {
                        liveTunnels.Add(tmpTnl.UID, tmpTnl);
                        if (!anyAdded) { anyAdded = true; }
                    }
                }
            }
            return liveTunnels;
        });
        return anyAdded;
    }

}
```

When there is no LiveTunnel of a client the entire client must be removed from the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Is there any better way to do so, specially in function `RemoveClientTunnel`?

**`Tunnel`**: Contains 10+ properties with database connections and socket connection.

For the current scenario, there are around 10,000+ clients and each client have at least 2 to 4 LiveTunnels, on an average 8 to 10 LiveTunnels per client.

**Frequency :** There are some time duration where the client connection frequencies are high. Eg, At 9:30 Am all clients starts to connect, around 12 Pm clients starts disconnecting (30-50%), around 2 PM clients re-connects, 5PM clients starts disconnecting.

A high traffic starts from 9:30Am. The frequency of tunnel: each clients holds the tunnel at least for 1-2 sec. minimum. If we count the minimum time duration a tunnel holds is minimum 1-2 Sec. There is no max time limit of a tunnel duration. A client can hold any number of tunnels for a very long time duration (18 Hours+)

Comment: Related: [How to achieve remove_if functionality in .NET ConcurrentDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679779/how-to-achieve-remove-if-functionality-in-net-concurrentdictionary). Also this: [ConcurrentDictionary with multiple values per key, removing empty entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695167/concurrentdictionary-with-multiple-values-per-key-removing-empty-entries).

Comment: I have updated the post with Stats and Current Scenario.

Comment: In your `AddOrUpdateClientTunnel` you can get rid of if statement with the ContainsKey call. You can use `liveTunnels[tnl.UID] = tnl;` in both situations and not need to check if the item is there at all. You still need the `lock` however.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `RemoveClientTunnel` is fundamentally broken, so it's hard to find a *worse* way to do it really, unless we get into grading how much more worse it can get.

Specifically, you're using the `ContainsKey` followed by `this[]` anti-pattern in a multi-threaded environment, which is a race condition if two different threads are trying to remove sessions. At the very least, the lock in that function should be moved up to above the `ContainsKey`, or even better use composite functions that handle atomicity for you, such as `TryGet` or `TryUpdate`.

In other words, either you handle atomicity yourself (such as with your lock, or even better something more granular that doesn't require you to run kernel code every single loop, like `ReaderWriterLockSlim`), or you rely completely on the `ConcurrentDictionary` implementation, but then you have to actually use its primitives, not do this mish-mash of code that drops atomicity randomly inbetween calls. On a long enough timeline, you'll see null reference exceptions on the `lock (liveTunls)` line, because the indexer couldn't find the item that `ContainsKey` claims is there.

Comment: I have to stick with ConcurrentDictionary, i have updated the post with the Stats and Frequencies of Tunnels. Any update in code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage scenario: "lots of clients with a few tunnels per client", indicates that using [immutable dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2) as values of the `ConcurrentDictionary` is a viable option. It's neither a [highly performant](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47812) nor a memory-efficient option, but it offers simplicity and easily provable correctness in return. Essentially by making the values of the `ConcurrentDictionary` immutable, you free yourself from most of the synchronization-related responsibility. The `ConcurrentDictionary` will provide the basic synchronization by itself, and you'll only have to resolve some edge cases by spinning, not by locking. Here is how you could do it:

```
public class ClientsConnections
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object,
        ImmutableDictionary<Guid, Tunnel>> _sessions = new();

    public Tunnel AddOrUpdateClientTunnel(object clientID, Tunnel tunnel)
    {
        if (tunnel.ClientID == null) tunnel.ClientID = clientID;
        _sessions.AddOrUpdate(clientID,
            _ => ImmutableDictionary.Create<Guid, Tunnel>().Add(tunnel.UID, tunnel),
            (_, existing) => existing.SetItem(tunnel.UID, tunnel));
        return tunnel;
    }

    public bool RemoveClientTunnel(object clientID, Tunnel tunnel)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!_sessions.TryGetValue(clientID, out var existing))
                return false; // clientID was not found

            var updated = existing.Remove(tunnel.UID);
            if (updated == existing) return false; // tnl.UID was not found

            if (updated.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (_sessions.TryRemove(KeyValuePair.Create(clientID, existing)))
                    return true; // Client successfully removed
            }
            else
            {
                if (_sessions.TryUpdate(clientID, updated, existing))
                    return true; // Client successfully updated
            }
            // We lost the race to either TryRemove or TryUpdate. Try again.
        }
    }
}
```

As an added bonus you would be able to get a snapshot of all the client connections at a specific point in time, by invoking the [`ConcurrentDictionary.ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.toarray?view=net-6.0) method. The immutable collections have snapshot semantics. You can enumerate them at your own leisure, without having to worry about concurrent updates invalidating the enumeration.

If you want to get fancy you could encapsulate the `TryGetValue`+`TryRemove`/`TryUpdate` spinning logic in an extension method `TryUpdateOrRemove` for the `ConcurrentDictionary` class, and use it like this:

```
public bool RemoveClientTunnel(object clientID, Tunnel tunnel)
{
    return _sessions.TryUpdateOrRemove(clientID,
        (_, existing) => existing.Remove(tunnel.UID));
}
```

The `TryUpdateOrRemove` method is [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/cdda43132b61cccd19d202361df1245e).

Comment: Does ImmutableDictionary have impact in Tunnels as it have socket connection and database connections, and Tunnels are accessed by UID (Key) of Tunnel ?

Comment: @Programmer no. The `ImmutableDictionary<K,V>` class is just a container, just like the `Dictionary<K,V>` class. There is nothing special about it, other than that it's immutable.